# Java LWJGL - Monster not following me, runs between a bounds of 2

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have written a script to be set off whenever a player is within a distance of the monster. The script checks if the x position is greater than or less than the players x, and same for the z. (y is automatically set to terrain)

```
public int checkWalkX(Vector3f position) {
    if (Math.floor(this.getX()) != Math.floor(position.x)) {
        if(this.getX() > position.x) return 1; //Greater
        if(this.getX() < position.x) return 2; //Less
    } 
    return 0;
}
public int checkWalkZ(Vector3f position) {
    if (Math.floor(this.getZ()) != Math.floor(position.z)) {
        if(this.getZ() > position.z) return 1; //Greater
        if(this.getZ() < position.z) return 2; //Less
    } 
    return 0;
}

public void follow(Player player) {
    walking = false;
    following = true;

    if(checkWalkX(player.getPosition()) == 1) this.setX(this.getX() - mobSpeed);
    else if(checkWalkX(player.getPosition()) == 2) this.setX(this.getX() + mobSpeed);

    if(checkWalkZ(player.getPosition()) == 1) this.setZ(this.getZ() - mobSpeed);
    else if(checkWalkZ(player.getPosition()) == 2) this.setZ(this.getZ() + mobSpeed);

    if(Math.floor(checkWalkX(walkToPosition)) == 0 && Math.floor(checkWalkZ(walkToPosition)) == 0) following = false;
}
```

For some reason when I run this script, the monster will only move within a distance of 2ish. He moves the right ways kinda, but he doesnt follow me. Would anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should leave out the Math.floor() condition.
What you could get right now is that the player for example is at *x=1* and the monster at *x=1.99*. The Floor condition would shorten this to *1 == 1* and declare that both are at the same place. In the worst case this would leave the monster at a distance of sqrt(2).

You can leave out the condition to get:

```
public int checkWalkX(Vector3f position) { 
    if(this.getX() > position.x) return 1; //Greater
    if(this.getX() < position.x) return 2; //Less
    return 0; // equal
}
```

The drawback of this is that you almost never get a zero back. The monster will always move. And here we come to the next problem. It always moves a fixed distance. This can lead to jumping around the target if the *mobspeed* is greater than the distance.

An approach to solve this could be to calculate the distance of the monster to the player (dist = sqrt(deltaX^2 + deltaZ^2)) and it this is greater than the desired distance move the monster along the monster-player-vector for a distance of *mobspeed* or *monster-player-distance* whichever is shorter.